# accessing ASP.NET controls in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have following Javascript line in my ASP.NET web app:

```
document.getElementById('<%=myTextBox[0].ClientID %>').value = "test";
```

how can I access myTextBox elements? for instance I want to change 5th element of this server side array, I want to pass a server side parameter to my function, how can I do it?

for instance:

```
server side:
ddl.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return OnFoodChange(this,'" + i + "');");


javascript function:
function OnFoodChange(myCmb,myIndex)
```

using `document.getElementById('<%=myTextBox[myIndex].ClientID %>').value = "test";` gives me error, it says that myIndex is not defined, I think because myIndex is used like a server side parameter, how can I solve it?

it is my full JavaScript function:

```
   function OnFoodChange(myCmb,myIndex) {
               //alert('5');
try{
               var q = document.getElementById('<%= HFFoodPrice.ClientID %>').value.toString();
           var q2 = q.split(';');
           var index = 0;
           //alert(myCmb.selectedIndex.toString());

           //var e = document.getElementById(myCmb);
           var strUser = myCmb.options[myCmb.selectedIndex].value;

           document.getElementById('<%=myTextBox[0].ClientID %>').value = strUser;

           for (var j = 0; j < q2.length; j++) {
               if (q2[j] != '') {
                   var q3 = q2[j].split(',');
                   {

                   }
               }
           }
           }
           catch(err)
           {
           alert(err.message);
           }
       }
```

Comment: can you post some detailed code so that I can help you better.

Comment: Are you sure your have a server side array of Textbox called myTextbox?  You need to elaborate further on what you are trying to do and how you are trying to do it.  Right now there are just bits and pieces of information to go off of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send this control id of textbox instead of sending index as asp.net control id might not be as you expect,

**In Code behind**

```
ddl.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return OnFoodChange(this,'" + myTextBox[i].ClientID + "');");
```

**In HTML**

```
function OnFoodChange(myCmb,myTextBoxId) {
 currentTextBox = document.getElementById(myTextBoxId);
//Your code...
}
```

Comment: I get this error: document.getElementById(myTextBoxId) is null

Comment: Do you assign id to every TextBox you have in myTextBox?

Comment: this is how I create my textboxes:      TextBox t = new TextBox();
                    myTextBox.Add(t);
is it right?

Comment: You have to assign id to TextBox before you add it to array.  TextBox t = new TextBox(); t.ID = "SomePrefixIfYouWant" + UniqueNumberMightBeLoopVariable.ToString(); myTextBox.Add(t);

Comment: I did just what you say, but still the same error occurs, how I use it in my Javascript function:document.getElementById(myTextBoxId).value = "test";

Comment: You have to reflect that thing over here too ddl.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return OnFoodChange(this,'" + i + "');");

Comment: you mean I should just send i? I did it but again the same error

Comment: You should not send it, you need to send the with the same naming convention you used for assigning id to TextBoxes with something like "SomePrefixIfYouWant" + UniqueNumberMightBeLoopVariable.ToString();

Comment: thanks, but I'm still getting the same error, ddl.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return OnFoodChange(this,'" + "txt" + i.ToString() + "');");

Comment: Please add your code for adding textbox in the page. I think you only add controls in array but do not add in page like Page.Controls.Add(t);

Comment: In fact I'm adding them to my table cells, I can view them in my screen.                     tc = new TableCell();
                    TextBox t = new TextBox();
                    t.ID = "txt" + i.ToString();
                    myTextBox.Add(t);
                    tc.Controls.Add(myTextBox[myTextBox.Count - 1]);
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc); myTable.Rows.Add(tr);

Comment: okay then view source of page in browser and see what ids you have with textboxes?

Comment: thanks, it is: id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt0", but is it safe to use this value? I think it would change, how can I find final value of this ID?

Comment: it does what I expected, but can I always expect to have this clientID?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13597/discussion-between-adil-and-ali-dotnet)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to Mix Server side with Client side. it does not work like this. you  need to transfer your server array to javascript on server then you will be able access its index on clien side.