# Could not access asp.net control ID in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this html structure:

```
<asp:Panel ID="divOne">
  <div class="divSection1">
  <asp:Panel runat="server" id="specialId" class="ClassOne ClassTwo"
    <asp:Label  id="MyLabel"></asp:Label>
    <div id="myDiv" </div>
  </asp:Panel>
  </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

And i am trying to access the "specialId" in jquery like $('#specialId'), $('div.specialId') with no success. Can someone advice?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389733/accessing-asp-net-controls-in-javascript . It does something similar

Comment: You should provide the actual generated HTML, and not your template code.

Comment: What does the actual client-side HTML look like?  JavaScript doesn't interact with your server-side code.

Comment: `runat="server"` seems to be missing on your tags. If possible, make a selection on the class. Or use the ClientID as stated by @ChiraqVidani

Answer (score 6):

My similar answer with a [little more explanation is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20227176/489512)

`runat="server"` in asp.net adds master and page information to each of its control. So, if you look at the DOM, your control would look something like this `master_page_ctrl0_specialId`[just an example].

You have a few options.

***Option1***: Use the client ID - recommended but meh.. not so much. I would try to avoid writing ClientID in javascript as much as possible.

```
$('#<%= specialId.ClientID %>')
```

***Option2***: Using the same ID - not recommended because its really ugly.

`$('[id$=specialId]')` or `$('[id*=specialId]')`

The above selectors are any id which ***ends with*** `specialID` and any id which ***contains*** `specialId` respectively.

***Option3***: Using the class - highly recommended. Because selectors using classes are clean and uncomplicated. Also, I see you've used `class`, use `CssClass` instead for .net controls.

```
$('.ClassOne.ClassTwo')
```

***Option4***: Use `ClientIDMode="Static"`, which got introduced in .NET Framework 4.0, on the control so that its ID will stay unchanged. - recommended too.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" id="specialId" CssClass="ClassOne ClassTwo">
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: There is also the overlooked 4th option of using Static ClientIDMode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should use actual generated HTML id using below syntax

That means you need to use client ID which can be accessed via below syntax

```
$('#<%= specialId.ClientID %>')
```

Comment: This doesn't work if your Javascript file is an external one though.  :(