# DIV Inner HTML in JQUERY

Tags: json, jquery

I am having a div. I am passing a HTML string to that div using INNERHTML in JSON. The div is not coming in the output.

Here is my code

```
$('#<%=btnSubmitData.ClientID %>').live('click', function () {
     var jsonParameters = '{"startProductLevelId":"' + prdLvlId1 + '"}';
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Test/Test.aspx/PopulateData",
            context: this,
            cache: false,
            data: jsonParameters,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
            "success": function (LastweeksData) {
             $("#brandData").css("display", "block");
             alert(LastweeksData.d); //Here i am getting the value
             document.getElementById('<%=brandData.ClientID%>').innerHTML = LastweeksData.d;
             },
             "error": function (request, status, error) {
              alert(error);
             }
          })
        });
```

My div - "brandData"

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <div id="dummy1" style="width: 100%; height: 20px; float: left">
     </div>
     <div id="Div2" style="width: 100%; height: 20px; float: right; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px;">
       <table id="Table1" align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="950">
         <tr>
             <td width="500" align="left" valign="top">
                  <div id="brandData" runat="server">
                   </div>
             </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
   </div>
```

I had also tried like this.

```
$("#brandData").innerHTML = LastweeksData.d;
```

I cant able the see the div in the output. I dont know where i am wrong.

Comment: the alert inside the success callback is firing?

Answer (score 0):

`$("#brandData").innerHTML` will not work as `$("#brandData")` returns a jQuery object not a dom element reference so it does not have the `innerHTML` property.

You can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html) utility method provided by jQuery to set the html content of an element.

Try

```
$("#brandData").html(LastweeksData.d)
```

Comment: i had tried like this "$("#brandData").html(LastweeksData.d);" but still i am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have `runat="server"` to the id `brandData`, so you cannot use `$("#brandData")` as a selector since the ID gets changed when it renders in the DOM with the prepended master and page information.(ex: `master_page_ctl100_brandData`)

```
<div id="brandData" runat="server">
```

Instead use `$('[id$=brandData]')` or `$('#<%=brandData.ClientID %>')` as your selector. There are few other options too.

A comprehensive list on how to target asp.net controls in jquery are [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860904/489512)

Comment: @RobinHood use $('[id$=brandData]').html()

Comment: I had tried like this "$('[id$=brandData]').innerHTML = LastweeksData.d;" and also tried '$('[id$=brandData]').html = LastweeksData.d;' and also "$('[id$=brandData]').html() = LastweeksData.d;"....Nothing seems to be working....

Comment: try this `$('[id$=brandData]').html(LastweeksData.d)`