# Update input type=text value or textbox control resize event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, resize

I have been having trouble updating the value for my input type=text or the texbox control text value with the jquery $(window).resize(function(){}); I know that the event fires because when i resize the browser an alert will appear. I also am using the functionality for something else.

It currently looks like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
if($(window).width()>1080){
var innerwidth = $(window).width()-170;
$("#div1").width(innerwidth);
}
```

I want to add this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
if($(window).height()>500){
var innerheight = $(window).height();
$('input.hiddentest').val(innerheight);
}
```

I know that the issue lies with:

```
$('input.hiddentest').val(innerheight);
```

I have also tried this:

```
$('#texttest.ClientID').text(innerheight);
```

This is the input and the textbox below that I am using(note that the type used to be hidden, but i dont think that makes an issue and I wanted it to be visible for debugging purposes)

```
<input id="hiddentest" type="text" visible="true" name="hiddentest" onclick="test();" runat="server" value="1000" />

<asp:TextBox id="texttest" Visible="true" runat="server" Text="1000" />
```

Overall I have been looking for a way to dynamically update the values as the page resizes with the size of the page. My geuss is that i am not using the right thing to identify the id's. Thanks for taking the time to look at this and for any replies.

P.S. I am also open to the idea of using a javascript function instead but i can't even seem to get the function to fire for the resize event so it would require more help.
This is what i have so far:

```
  window.onresize=Test();
  function Test(){
  var hdnfld= document.getElementById("texttest");
  var testing = window.innerWidth;
  alert(testing);
  hdnfld.text= testing;
  }
```

Comment: Your jQuery version is missing the closing `});`. Your non-jQuery version should be `window.onresize=Test;` (without the `()` after `Test`). Also, [indent your code](http://www.jspretty.com/).

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers you were all right. I ended up needing to use a javascript function because it was using a custom function called getElement as opposed to getElementById. the answers below would have worked otherwise. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use just ID of elements without dots (that actually represent the classes you don't have).

So use

```
$('#hiddentest').val(innerheight)
```

and

```
$('#texttest').val(innerheight)
```

Note that `asp:TextBox` renders as `inptut type="text"` so you still have to use `.val()` on it, not `.text()`

Comment: text test is an asp textbox control so it uses text, and as stated below i tried $('#hiddentest').val(innerheight). Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: @NicholasTylek it is ASPX textbox, correct. But see what it looks like in your browser (View Page Source). jQuery (and normal JavaScript) operates on client-side elements, *not* on the original ASP.NET control. There could be big difference between the 2 (even including IDs)

Comment: Ok I will make sure to check the page source. I didn't know the ID's could be different. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Hidden text box id is "hiddentest" so the code will be

```
            $('#hiddentest').val(innerheight);
```

Answer (score 1):

`hiddentest` is an `id` not a `class` in your case

Try,

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   if($(window).height()>500){
     var innerheight = $(window).height();
     $('#hiddentest').val(innerheight);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox id="texttest" Visible="true" runat="server" Text="1000" />
```

For the above asp.net textbox control, the ID changes dynamically when rendered (prepended with master and page information), id looks similar to `main_ctrl100_texttest`

`var hdnfld= document.getElementById("texttest");`, so this no longer holds good. Use a class instead.

```
<asp:TextBox id="texttest" Visible="true" runat="server" CssClass="texttest" Text="1000" />

var hdnfld = document.getElementsByClassName("texttest");
```

If you need more info on how to access .net controls using jquery, [see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20227176/489512)

Comment: Thank you for the link and the explanation. It definitely helps explain alot. i was really having trouble accessing .net controls as well as html.

Comment: @NicholasTylek - great .. glad to help. please upvote all helpful answers and accept one as an answer.

Comment: I only have a reputation of 6. When i get to 15 I gladly will. thanks again.