# How to get User Control ID and apply jQuery .click() function in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-controls

I have menu like this :

```
 <li class="active" id="liHome"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlHome" runat="server" Text="Home" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx"></asp:HyperLink></li>
      <li><asp:HyperLink ID="hlRegister" runat="server" Text="Register" NavigateUrl="~/register.aspx"></asp:HyperLink></li>
      <li><asp:HyperLink ID="hlLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" NavigateUrl="~/login.aspx"></asp:HyperLink></li>
      <li><asp:HyperLink ID="hlBug" runat="server" Text="Report A Bug" NavigateUrl="~/bug.aspx"></asp:HyperLink></li>
      <li><asp:HyperLink ID="hlContactUs" runat="server" Text="Contact Us" NavigateUrl="~/contact.aspx"></asp:HyperLink></li>
```

Using Javascript as in header :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= hlHome.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            alert("ok working")
             $('#liHome').removeClass("active"); // not working
        });
    });
```

Alert is working in click butits not removing class active from li why ? I am also using update panel. what is the silution to get it done while using update panel.

Comment: you cannot use ids directly for asp.net controls. Use CssClass or `ClientIDMode="Static"` or  [More comprehensive info here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20227176/489512)

Comment: @Krishna he does not need to use the ids

Comment: @krishna thanks :) i was not using # in $('#') :) Thankyou .

Comment: @zgood what the better option can be please ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad see below and please let me know if you have any questions or if it is not working. I will help you.

Comment: @zgood - I agree that OP doesn't need to in this particular case. but what if the hyperlinks are not part of the `ul` dom structure anymore or what if the ul's class changes? for .net controls in particular there is a specific way to target.

Comment: @Krishna Yes that is a very valid point.

Comment: @zgood its not working whn page completley loads it again apply class active to first li. Kindly guide me :) thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe try something like this:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
       function pageLoad() {
           var loc = window.location.href.split('/');
           var page = loc[loc.length - 1];
           $('ul.nav a').each(function (i) {
               var href = $(this).attr('href');
               if (href.indexOf(page) !== -1) {
                   $('ul.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
                   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
               }
           });
       }
   </script>
```

For `UpdatePanels` I believe you can use the `pageLoad` function instead of `$(document).ready`

Comment: its not working in my case. when i click a it applys active class but when page loads completley it again shows first li active . please help me ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you using `UpdatePanels` ?

Comment: Also, `$('#liHome').removeclass("active");` is wrong it needs to be `$('#liHome').removeClass("active");` `removeClass` has a capital C in jquery

Comment: How to use your piece of code its just an amazing thing. I am beginner but how you worked with DOM is really impressive :) @zgood

Comment: I was using Capital C but as you raised that am I using update panel so might be because of that its creating problem. Can you please suggest me how to work with I do not want to remove my update panel @zgood

Comment: @AfnanAhmad It does get a bit tricky with `UpdatePanels`, but try the above code and let me know if you have any success.

Comment: unfortunately , I used your above code with page load but with no luck. @zgood

Comment: I have updated my answer, let me know if this new approach works or if you have any questions

Comment: when I run my project at the very first time its not showing class active to home while when i click on some  menu item it works fine. But I need home to be active at very first time

Comment: thankyou so much :) I have just changed one line and now its working perfectly :) . Wao you have written an amazing code :)