# ASP.NET link button doesn't work with jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a jQuery plugin that is use for tabbing menu like this code:

```
div id="tabsWithStyle" class="style-tabs">
        <ul>
             <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Tozih"  OnClick="Tozih_Click" href="#facebook"  runat="server"><div class="icon picasa-icon">توضیح</div></asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
                <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="books" OnClick="books_Click"     runat="server"><div class="icon picasa-icon">کتاب</div></asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
              <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="jozve" OnClick="jozve_Click"  href="#facebook"  runat="server"><div class="icon picasa-icon">جزوه</div></asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
</ul>
```

and the jQuery is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#tabsWithStyle').tabs();
        });
    </script>
```

also #facebook is a div

```
   <div id="facebook">
countent
</div>
```

Edit : it's server-side event (C# code).

My problem is that `onClick` events don't work when I click on it

What's my problem ?

Edit 2 :

[image]

Edit 3:

```
protected void books_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("NewsFeed.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Is books_Click referring to server side event handler?

Comment: Use `onclientclick` to refer client side events!

Comment: and lastly $('#id_of_control').click(function() { }); will hook up client side event handling with jquery.

Comment: @brumScouse yes its a server side ( c# )

Comment: can you also add the output HTML probably it is rendering some layout tabs plugin does like..

Comment: I meant HTML just view source in the browser and copy-past the div#tabsWithStyle. and as a other suggestion what happens when you try the tab with html a tag instead of asp.net just give it a link...

Comment: are you saying the server event is not getting fired? Did you write `protected` for the event in C#? Can you please add that to your question?  Or client event?

Comment: @Krishna server event is not getting fired

Comment: @Krishna i added that event

Comment: @Oli - if you have `href="#facebook"` it doesn't work, it will override the server event. But if you remove the href attribute, it will work.

Comment: @krishna if i remove href="#facebook" the jquery will be stop!

Comment: @Oli - adding href attribute is not jquery. You might want to handle a client side click event & return false/true based on your requirement. also it's not valid to have href to .net LinkButton

Comment: @Oli - helpful info here.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20227176/489512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#Tozih").on("click", function(event){
alert("clicked on Tozih"); 
});
```

Comment: its a server side event

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using serverside control you need to use client id:

```
$('#<%= Tozih.ClientID %>').on('click', function(){
  //your code, 'this' is a clicked element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In your Linkbutton add one attribute causesvalidation

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="jozve" OnClick="jozve_Click" causesvalidation="false"  href="#facebook"  runat="server"><div class="icon picasa-icon">جزوه</div></asp:LinkButton>
```