# Issue related to getting ClientID of asp controls in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have asp.net webApplication having asp controls.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdTime" runat="server" />
```

To Access above control in Javascript i have used `$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdTime').val('AM');`

it works fine in Mozila firefox but in InternetExplorer it takes 
    `$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdTime').val('AM');`

i have also tried

```
$('#<%= hdTime.ClientID %>')
```

but above syntext works only on .aspx page but when i use javascript.js file it doesn't find as `$('#<%= hdTime.ClientID %>')`

so how to access asp controls  in .js file??

Thanks

Comment: look at the html generated by your asp control, and see what's its id...

Comment: you can also look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860085/could-not-access-asp-net-control-id-in-jquery

Answer (score 2):

You can set `Clientidmode="static"` for the control..

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdTime" runat="server" Clientidmode="static"/>
```

**Javascript:**

//Accessing control in javascript

```
var abc=document.getelementbyid('hdTime').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using static client side ids:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This issue is because the ids generated by webforms are dynamic, so you cannot hard code them. However, webforms 4 introduced static client side ids to solve the issue you are having.

For example, add this attribute to your control: `ClientIDMode="Static"`, and then you can reference your control in JavaScript like this:

`$('#hdTime')`

If you can't use webforms v4 then you will have to put your JavaScript in the aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this : `<asp:HiddenField ID="hdTime" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />`

you can find the ID of the control, also important is to give **ClientIDMode="Static"**

var id = Document.getElememtById("hdTime").value;

or

var id = $("#hdTime").val();